# The problem of not running the second loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

*I am looking for a code to transfer 10% of the row  highest data to another sheet.
In the first part of the code that I wrote, the data is recognized correctly, but in the second part, where the data must be transferred to another sheet, the code does not run.
Please guide me*

```
Sub CopyHighlightedTransactions()
Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:b7")
myrange.Interior.Pattern = xlnon
For Each mycell In myrange
For i = 1 To 2
If mycell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(myrange, i) Then
mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
Next
Next mycell
Dim TransIDField As Range
Dim TransIDCell As Range
Dim ATransWS As Worksheet
Dim HTransWS As Worksheet
Set ATransWS = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set TransIDField = ATransWS.Range("A2", ATransWS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set HTransWS = Worksheets("sheet2")
For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField
    If TransIDCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
                TransIDCell.Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:= _
            HTransWS.Range("A1").Offset(HTransWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
               End If
Next TransIDCell
HTransWS.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is highlighting the 2 largest values in `Sheet1!A1:B7`, but your copying loop is only looking at the first column (from `Sheet1!A2` down) so, if the 2 largest values happen to be in `Sheet1!A1` or `Sheet1!B1:B7` then it won't 'see' them...
btw you should declare **all** of your variables (i.e. `i`)if you want to avoid problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using already defined range ?

```
Sub CopyHighlightedTransactions()
    Dim i As Long, nTopRows As Long
    
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim ATransWS As Worksheet

    Set ATransWS = Worksheets("sheet1")
    '
    ' search maximum on the column A:
    '
    'Set myrange = ATransWS.Range("a1", ATransWS.Range("b1").End(xlDown))
    '
    Set myrange = ATransWS.Range("A2", ATransWS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    '
    ' 10% of total rows:
    '
    nTopRows = Int(myrange.Rows.Count * 0.1)
    
    '
    'myrange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    'myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    'myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    
    For Each mycell In myrange
        Rows(mycell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        For i = 1 To nTopRows
            If mycell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(myrange, i) Then
                '
                'mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                '
                Rows(mycell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next
    Next mycell

    Dim TransIDField As Range
    Dim TransIDCell As Range
    Dim HTransWS As Worksheet

    'Set TransIDField = ATransWS.Range("A2", ATransWS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set TransIDField = myrange
    
    Set HTransWS = Worksheets("sheet2")
    
    For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField
        If TransIDCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            TransIDCell.Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:= _
                HTransWS.Range("A1").Offset(HTransWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next TransIDCell
    
    HTransWS.Columns.AutoFit

    
    Set mycell = Nothing
    Set myrange = Nothing
    Set ATransWS = Nothing
    
    Set TransIDField = Nothing
    Set TransIDCell = Nothing
    Set HTransWS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: In the code above, it only colors one cell, while I want the row to be colored and the entire colored row to be copied, what should I do?

Comment: You've highlighted only 2 values in the first part of code. So maximum you'll transfer 2 items.

Comment: I want to color the row corresponding to that cell after identifying the most data؟For example, first, the highest amount of sales is identified, and finally, the sales amount and the name of the person that are in one line are copied and transferred to another sheet.